# Column widths change (on table with 100% width) when row is toggled

Tags: jquery, css, html-table

I can't believe this has stumped me.

I have a table with a width of 100%.
I have columns, some of which have their widths defined.
I have 2 types of row throughout my table. Some are always visible, some appear when the row above them are clicked on.

Html:

```
<table border="1" style="width: 100%;">
    <tr class="a">
        <td colspan="2" style="width: 50px">
            A
        </td>
        <td style="width: 40px">
            A
        </td>
        <td>
            A
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="b">
        <td>
            A
        </td>
        <td style="width: 10px;">
            A
        </td>
        <td>
            A
        </td>
        <td>
            A
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $(".b").hide();

    $(".a").click(function(){
        $(".b").toggle();
    })
})
```

Here is a JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/9hnp9Lxf/

It couldn't be simpler... but I cannot work out why this won't act the way I want.

Can someone please advise?

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: How do you want it to act? It is displaying the row below when I click the first row...

Comment: I don't want the widths to change on toggle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "colgroup" and "col" tag to define the table structure. Then you will not face this issue since structure will fixed by these tags. for ex:

```
  <colgroup>
    <col span="2" style="width:50px" >
    <col style="width:30px">
  </colgroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want table columns to respect width set with CSS you can define [fixed table layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout):

```
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9hnp9Lxf/2/

Answer (score 0):

It's because the table maintains it's structure throughout depending upon the number of columns and data inside it . Why you are facing this problem can be summarized briefly from the following points :-

- Firstly , you have three columns in the first row .
- Secondly , you have four columns in the second row .
- Thirdly , you have widths of `td`s all different(I am talking about the `td`s in the same `columns`.

To maintain the `tr-td` structure , Table adjusts itself . In your case , when you click on the first row , the second row having four columns (4 `td`s) opens up adjusting with the previous `tr`  .The first two `td`s of the second row comes down under the first `td` of the first row . Try adding more columns in the second row , you will see the changes accordingly but the table structure will not be disturbed . It will remain 100% throughout .

`table-layout:fixed` will solve your problem but it is not a good practice in every case .It doesn't work as well cross-browsers . Also you don't want widths to get change on `toggle` , `table-layout:fixed` will then not solve your issue .

Comment: Nice one. This seems sucky tbh... surely I am not the only person who wants to do this?